# Callback success function doesn't receive data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

**Background:** I am inserting into a page content from external php file thru ajax.
**Constraint:** I want to follow object structure described in [How to “properly” create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/775066).
**Problem:** But along with this structure I don't receive the response data in success callback. In firebug I can see the **correct** html which was returned by post.

## Problematic code:

```
// Abstract class for functionality of both QuizView and QuizAdmin
Quiz = Object.makeSubclass();
Quiz.prototype._init= function() {};
Quiz.prototype.fetchSuccess= function(data) {
    // fetchSuccess must be defined before fetch.
    console.log("Quiz.prototype.fetchSucces"); // This gets printed out - so the function is called.
    console.log(this.targetElement); // echoes the correct element - when I hoover it, I see it in the page.
    console.log(data); // echoes undefined
    this.targetElement.append(data); // Obviously this line is what I want to do.
};
//This function gets content specified by url.
Quiz.prototype.fetch= function(what,where) {
    console.log("Quiz.prototype.fetch");
    this.targetElement=where;
    console.log(this.targetElement);
    // Get the the content
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: what,
          success: this.fetchSuccess,
          targetElement: this.targetElement,
          dataType: "html",
          async: false
    });
}; // End Quiz.prototype.fetch
```

**Note:** Basically the only difference between the *Related question* bellow and my code is that I use `function expression` and not `function declaration`. Which is because I want to follow the structure as described in *constraint*.

## Related questions:

[Jquery ajax external callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275308/jquery-ajax-external-callback-function)
[JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
[Where to define a jQuery $.ajax() success function if you don't want to define in the call to $.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
[jQuery ajax success callback function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition)

## Simple code organization (this works!)

```
function fetchSuccess(data){
  $(".content-bottom").append(data);
}

  $(document).ready(function(){
  // Get the view content
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../../../../includes/quiz1/index.php",
      success: fetchSuccess,
      dataType: "html", 
      async: false
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

You are passing function reference and `this` inside  `fetchSuccess` is not what you expecting

```
// Abstract class for functionality of both QuizView and QuizAdmin
Quiz = Object.makeSubclass();
Quiz.prototype._init= function() {};
Quiz.prototype.fetchSuccess= function(data) {
    // fetchSuccess must be defined before fetch.
    console.log("Quiz.prototype.fetchSucces"); // This gets printed out - so the function is called.
    console.log(this.targetElement); // echoes the correct element - when I hoover it, I see it in the page.
    console.log(data); // echoes undefined
    this.targetElement.append(data); // Obviously this line is what I want to do.
};
//This function gets content specified by url.
Quiz.prototype.fetch= function(what,where) {
    console.log("Quiz.prototype.fetch");
    this.targetElement=where;
    console.log(this.targetElement);
    // Get the the content
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: what,
          success: function(){self.fetchSuccess.apply(self, arguments)}, 
          targetElement: this.targetElement,
          dataType: "html",
          async: false
    });
};
```

Comment: Isn't `success: function(){self.fetchSuccess.apply(self, arguments)}` equal to `success: self.fetchSuccess` ?

Comment: @JAM no, not at all.  success: self.fetchSuccess will set scope of fetchSuccess different from its original scope.

Comment: @JAM, Dude what you want to prove. I am saying this inside will get changed not arguments. argument will be same. for example in above case this.targetElement will be undefined as this got changed

Comment: @Sushil: Just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately the result is the same: data is undefined :-(

Comment: @Sushil: No `this.targetElement` goes in as data (ajax 4th line).

Comment: @JAM check your example http://jsfiddle.net/rPFFR/1/. variable this does not represent instance of MyObject.

Comment: @sumid I am not talking about data I am  talking about this variable inside function. BTW data will be same in all cases(depend what server send)

Comment: @JAM: Unfortunately your example from jsfiddle won't get along with the inheritance pattern :-( [How to “properly” create a custom object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/775066)